# Programmatically update react navigation header title in functional component with hooks

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

question regarding react navigation setParams(). I asked on Reactiflux, but no one responded. I'm trying to set a title programmatically in a function component.

From another Stack Overflow thread, updating the static title retroactively, like this, works:

```
const Comp = props => { ... };

Comp.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  title: 'Static Title'
});
```

But I need to access the component state from *within* the component, this does not work:

```
const Comp =({ navigation }) => {
 const [title, setTitle] = useState('');

 useEffect(() => {
     navigation.setParams({ title });
 }, [title]);

 return ( ... );
}
```

If setParams() is the wrong way to do it, please enlighten me

EDIT: To add to this, when I `console.log(navigation)` I can see that it is changing `navigation.state.params.title` to the correct string, however it doesn't show up as the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to get the title param and apply it to the title:

```js
Comp.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  title: navigation.getParam('title', /* your default title */)
});
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. To be clear for anyone finding this thread, I still need to use `setParams()` from within the component to actually set the title, then `getParams()` is able to find that title later

Comment: I have written like this ProductDetails.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  title: "Static Title"
});
export default ProductDetails; but still it is not working. Any extra configuration required

Comment: Spent 2-3 hours before I came across this.... thanks a lot! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to implement your navigation option as a function and this function needs navigation parameter as shown example in following lines :

   ```
   const cameraScreenNavigator = {
    '/auth/controlledCameraScreen': {
    screen: ControlledCameraScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation?.getParam('title', "Başvuru Adı"),
    headerStyle: style.navigationHeaderBlue,
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: COLORS.primaryText
       },
     }),
    }
   }
   ```
2. Then you can call setParams function in your component. This function acting as setState but react-nativagion suggests this for
   setParams "setParams/setOptions etc. should only be called in useEffect/useLayoutEffect/componentDidMount/componentDidUpdate etc. Not during render or in constructor."

   ```
   props.navigation.setParams({title: "New Title"})
   ```

resource : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/